# Android ending call and going to home screen

Tags: android

I tried to make an Android program where I can call a single number by clicking button. Works fine but as I end calling, the emulator shows call log. Instead of this I would that my program returns to the screen where is that calling button I made. How can I do this? My code is now like this

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.soita)).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
String nro="9999999";
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+nro));
startActivity(intent1);
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: I found that when I end the call in a button, the Activity Manager displays

Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.VIEW type=vnd.anroid.cursor.dir/calls comp={com.andoid

and then I can't see the rest of line in Eclipse.

Can I change this intent somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```